# Can I simplify these nested javascript "if" statements into one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

So I have two variables, animationFlag and ajaxFlag. I also have a function setup that returns true or false based on browser support of transitions. That I'd like to happen is that it only runs this fadein function if ajaxFlag is true AND animationFlag is true. But in a browser without transition support, animationFlag will never become true so I need to check if it supports transitions, then check for the ajaxFlag only if transitions aren't supported. I tried separating them with || and && in different combinations, but I really need this nesting.

A single if statement would be WAYYYY nice, so, is it possible to combine that into one? Thanks!

```
    function checkDone() {
        if (!supportsTransitions) {
            if (ajaxFlag) {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    fadeInModal();
                },100)
            }
        } else {
            if (ajaxFlag && animationFlag) {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    fadeInModal();
                },100)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work

```
if (ajaxFlag && (animationFlag || !supportsTransitions)) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Awesome dude! I didn't realize you could separate them out in parenthesis like that.

Comment: Great to hear it worked out for you. Always glad to help. :D May I suggest this change as well: `setTimeout(fadeInModal, 100);`? If `fadeInModal` doesn't take in any arguments, this should also save you the overhead of an extra function call. :)

Comment: Thanks mate! I've been using anonymous functions. I suck at JS.

Comment: If it has arguments, does it need to be in an anonymous function?

Comment: If it has arguments, the cleanest way (in my opinion) of doing it is the way you originally did actually. :p That is, call the function inside an anonymous.